# java вычисление центра треугольника

Tags: java

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с заданием.

Дано: класс Point, скелет класса Triangle.

Реализуйте методы Triangle:

конструктор, имеющий в качестве параметров три точки.

Эти точки относятся к вершинам треугольника.

Убедитесь, что созданный треугольник существует и не является дегенеративным. \

double area()

Верните площадь треугольника.

Point centroid()

Верните центр тяжести треугольника.

```
class Point {
private double x;
private double y;

public Point(final double x, final double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public double getX() {
    return x;
}

public double getY() {
    return y;
}
}

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    {
        double area = new Triangle(new Point(0, 0), new Point(3, 0), new Point(0, 4)).area();
        System.out.println(area);
    }
    {
        Point centroid = new Triangle(new Point(0, 0), new Point(3, 0), new Point(0, 3)).centroid();

        System.out.println(centroid.getX());
        System.out.println(centroid.getY());
    }
}
}
```

Вот что у меня получилось:

```
 class Triangle {
 Point a,b,c;
 double length1,length2,length3;

 public Triangle(Point a, Point b, Point c) {
     if (a == null || b == null || c == null) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Arguments can't be null");
         if (((length1+length2) < length3)||((length1+length3) < length2)||((length2+length3) < 
  length1)) {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Triangle is degenerative");
         }
      }
         this.a = a;
         this.b = b;
         this.c = c;
     }

 double length1(Point a, Point b) {
     double xDistanceSquare = Math.pow(a.getX() - b.getX(), 2);
     double yDistanceSquare = Math.pow(a.getY() - b.getY(), 2);
     return Math.sqrt(xDistanceSquare + yDistanceSquare);
 }
 double length2(Point a, Point c) {
     double xDistanceSquare = Math.pow(a.getX() - c.getX(), 2);
     double yDistanceSquare = Math.pow(a.getY() - c.getY(), 2);
     return Math.sqrt(xDistanceSquare + yDistanceSquare);
 }
 double length3(Point c, Point b) {
     double xDistanceSquare = Math.pow(c.getX() - b.getX(), 2);
     double yDistanceSquare = Math.pow(c.getY() - b.getY(), 2);
     return Math.sqrt(xDistanceSquare + yDistanceSquare);
 }

 public double area( ) {
  double s= (length1+length2+length3)/2;
  return  Math.sqrt(s*(s-length1)*(s-length2)*(s-length3));
 }

 public Point centroid(){
     double xc= (((a.getX()+b.getX()+c.getX())/3));
     double yc= (((a.getY()+b.getY()+c.getY())/3));
     return new Point(xc, yc);
 }
```

}

Я точно как-то не так сделал проверку в конструкторе + я не понимаю а куда собственно я выбрасываю исключения, если в класcе Main, данном заранее, перехвата этих исключений нет? То есть мне надо в Triangle его прописать?

Comment: Если исключение никто не ловит, то приложение ваше прекращает работу.

Comment: Кажется, я уже видел этот вопрос. Вы его заново задали что ли?

Comment: Когда вы пишете класс, вас не должно беспокоить, кто будет ловить и обрабатывать исключения, и будет ли кто-нибудь вообще. Ваша задача -- гарантировать, что если уж объект вашего класса создан, то он будет вести себя правильно. Класс `Main` -- это просто минимальная проверка работоспособности вашего класса, от него не требуется корректная обработка исключений (во всяком случае, это не ваша ответственность). В случае возникновения исключений программа просто вылетит и выдаст сообщение о месте ошибки, для простых тестовых программ это допустимо. Обработку исключения делать нигде не надо.

Answer (score 0):

Как это куда выбрасываются исключения? У вас в конструкторе класса всё прописано, при создании объекта класса (а вы ведь в любом случае его создаёте, иначе для чего вам собственно данный класс), вызывается его конструктор и, соответственно, всё, что вы прописали в конструкторе - будет выполняться. Если условия выполняются, выбрасывается искусственно прописанное вами исключение IllegalArgumentException. Это же не обработка исключений, вы сами его и указали. И вообще, ваши переменные длины отрезков ничего не хранят, вы их создали не проинициализировав и пытаетесь их с чем-то сравнить в конструкторе, так ещё и используете их для подсчёта площади, да там вообще не должно компилироваться, ссылаясь на nullptrexception.
И ещё :

```
if (((length1+length2) < length3)||((length1+length3) < length2)||((length2+length3) < length1)) {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Triangle is degenerative");
         }
```

-это не будет работать. Раз вы решаете такие задачи, то, возможно, изучаете языки программирования уже несколько месяцев, и вам должна быть известна информация о строгих и нестрогих неравенствах и как они работают в представлении машинного кода.

```
if (((length1+length2) <= length3)||((length1+length3) <= length2)||((length2+length3) <=  length1)) {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Triangle is degenerative");
         }
```

-это правильный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Метод определения площади так не будет работать ибо методы lenght не проинициализированы. Мое решение выглядит вот так. Судя по всему не самое красивое решение, но рабочее) Кстати, спасибо за формулы

```
private double length3() {
        double xDistanceSquare = Math.pow(c.getX() - b.getX(), 2.0);
        double yDistanceSquare = Math.pow(c.getY() - b.getY(), 2.0);
        return Math.sqrt(xDistanceSquare + yDistanceSquare);
    }

    private double length2() {
        double xDistanceSquare = Math.pow(a.getX() - c.getX(), 2.0);
        double yDistanceSquare = Math.pow(a.getY() - c.getY(), 2.0);
        return Math.sqrt(xDistanceSquare + yDistanceSquare);
    }

    private double length1() {
        double xDistanceSquare = Math.pow(a.getX() - b.getX(), 2.0);
        double yDistanceSquare = Math.pow(a.getY() - b.getY(), 2.0);
        return Math.sqrt(xDistanceSquare + yDistanceSquare);
    }

public double area() {
       
        length1 = length1();
        length2 = length2();
        length3 = length3();
        double s= (length1+length2+length3)/2;
        return  Math.sqrt(s*(s-length1)*(s-length2)*(s-length3));
```